# Order by with complex relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a complex and confused scenary.

I need order by prices. But, I have a logic on prices...

```
cad_product
id
title
store_id

cad_store
id
business_model

//This table can be associated to 1 or more products...
cad_sku
id
product_id

cad_price_sku
id
sku_id
retail
sale_retail
wholesale
sale_wholesale
```

I need sql order by prices, but the same product can contain 1 or more SKUs, and the next SKU, can contain a less price than the first. That is, I need pass for each product SKU and return that minor price.

Besides that, I've a business_model logic. Where a product can be shown through your B2C prices (retail and sale_retail), B2B prices (wholesale and sale_wholesale) e BOTH (both b2b and b2c prices).

I've tried something similar to this.

```
SELECT cad_product.title, skuP.retail, skuP.sale_retail, skuP.wholesale, skuP.sale_wholesale 
FROM cad_product
INNER JOIN cad_sku sku ON cad_product.id = sku.product_id
INNER JOIN cad_price_table_sku skuP ON sku.id = skuP.sku_id
INNER JOIN cad_store store ON store.id = cad_product.store_id
WHERE cad_product.deleted_at IS NULL
AND ((skuP.sale_retail <> 0 AND skuP.retail <> 0))
ORDER BY skuP.sale_retail asc, skuP.retail asc, skuP.sale_wholesale asc, skuP.wholesale asc;
```

And this result...

```
+-----------------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
| title                       | retail | sale_retail | wholesale | sale_wholesale |
+-----------------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
| Produto de teste - Loja B2C |   1.50 |        1.00 |      0.75 |           0.50 |
| Produto de teste - Loja B2C |  20.00 |       18.00 |     80.00 |           0.00 |
| Novamente TESTE             | 125.23 |     4892.13 |    800.00 |         400.00 |
+-----------------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you  please better specify what you want to order by? Do you need to order by the "least"/"minimum" price of all the different SKU prices?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your time. I need to order by the lowest prices of all SKU by product, being that, the order should works case the price of product either b2b or b2c or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I am understanding you correctly, you want to order by the minimum lowest price of the 4 price columns.

That is done this way

```
SELECT cad_product.title, skuP.retail, skuP.sale_retail, skuP.wholesale, skuP.sale_wholesale 
FROM cad_product
INNER JOIN cad_sku sku ON cad_product.id = sku.product_id
INNER JOIN cad_price_table_sku skuP ON sku.id = skuP.sku_id
INNER JOIN cad_store store ON store.id = cad_product.store_id
WHERE cad_product.deleted_at IS NULL
AND ((skuP.sale_retail <> 0 AND skuP.retail <> 0))
ORDER BY LEAST(skuP.sale_retail, skuP.retail, skuP.sale_wholesale, skuP.wholesale) asc;
```